# List primary replicas and non-HA databases - excluding forwarder replicas

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, dmv, distributed-availability-groups

When asking **which databases are writable** on any given server, I've been using the below snippet to list `PRIMARY` replica databases and databases that do not participate in an AG.

Now that I've deployed a [Distributed Availability Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/distributed-availability-groups), it's not working anymoar! Since the local forwarder reports as a `PRIMARY` replica on the [`sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-hadr-availability-replica-states-transact-sql) DMV, my old query is telling me a database is writable when it is not.

> How do I change this query to **exclude databases in a local forwarder replica**?

```
select 
    ars.role_desc
   ,ag_name = ag.[name]
   ,adc.[database_name]
from sys.availability_groups ag 
join sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states ars on ars.group_id = ag.group_id
join sys.availability_databases_cluster adc on adc.group_id = ag.group_id
where ars.is_local = 1
    and ars.role_desc = 'PRIMARY'
union all 
select 
    'LOCAL_ONLY'
   ,@@servername
   ,[name]
from sys.databases d 
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from sys.availability_databases_cluster adc
    where adc.[database_name] = d.[name]
);
```

...or more simply...

> How do I list all local forwarder databases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To list all databases in an forwarder replica on the current server...

```
select 
     dag.group_id
    ,dag.[name]
    ,dag.is_distributed
    ,fwd.replica_id
    ,fwd.replica_server_name
    ,adc.[database_name]
from sys.availability_groups dag 
join sys.availability_replicas fwd on fwd.group_id = dag.group_id
join sys.availability_groups ag on ag.name = fwd.replica_server_name
join sys.availability_databases_cluster adc on adc.group_id = ag.group_id
where dag.is_distributed = 1;
```

To list all databases that are `PRIMARY` or local only and exclude forwarder databases...

```
select 
    ars.role_desc
   ,ag_name = ag.[name]
   ,adc.[database_name]
from sys.availability_groups ag 
join sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states ars on ars.group_id = ag.group_id
join sys.availability_databases_cluster adc on adc.group_id = ag.group_id
where ars.is_local = 1
    and ars.role_desc = 'PRIMARY'
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from sys.availability_groups dag 
        join sys.availability_replicas fwd on fwd.group_id = dag.group_id
        join sys.availability_groups ag2 on ag2.name = fwd.replica_server_name
        join sys.availability_databases_cluster db on db.group_id = ag2.group_id
        where dag.is_distributed = 1
            and db.[database_name] = adc.[database_name]
)
union all 
select 
    'LOCAL_ONLY'
   ,@@servername
   ,[name]
from sys.databases d 
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from sys.availability_databases_cluster adc
    where adc.[database_name] = d.[name]
);
```